# Programmatically fade elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm working on a the script of the century which creates and deletes elements in set intervals, but I need to fade the elements first before deleting them. I'd like for this effect to be done programmatically and with JavaScript only.

I tried to add fade out animations like so:

```
function createRandomDiv () {
  ...
  randomDiv.style.opacity = "1";
  randomDiv.style.transition = "opacity 0.1s ease-out";
  ...
}
```

Then listen to the 'animationend' event to delete it, but it doesn't seen to be fading out.

```
function deleteRandomDiv () {
  ...
  div.style.opacity = "0";
  div.addEventListener('animationend', function () {
    this.remove();
  });
  ...
}
```

Here is a bin of what I have so far: https://jsbin.com/nuqeyutopu/edit?

What I had:

```js
console.clear();
document.body.style.position = "fixed";
document.body.style.height = "100%";
document.body.style.width = "100%";
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#EFEFEF";

var numDivs = 20;
var maxSize = 400;

function createRandomDiv() {
    var randomDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var size = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxSize) + "px";
    randomDiv.style.height = size;
    randomDiv.style.width = size;
    randomDiv.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    randomDiv.style.position = "absolute";
    randomDiv.style.top = getRandomPosition();
    randomDiv.style.left = getRandomPosition();
    randomDiv.style.display = "block";
    randomDiv.style.borderRadius = "500px";
    randomDiv.innerHTML = "&nbsp";
    randomDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/filthy-frank/images/8/8d/516c32f08e03d.png/revision/latest?cb=20151019010624)";
    randomDiv.style.backgroundSize="contain";
    document.body.appendChild(randomDiv);
}

function createDivs() {
  for(var i = 0; i < numDivs; i++) {
    createRandomDiv();
  }
}

function getRandomPosition() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "%";
}

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function deleteRandomDiv() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  divs[Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length)].remove();
}

createDivs();

setInterval(function () {
  createRandomDiv();
  deleteRandomDiv();
}, 50);
```

Comment: Have you thought about having your deleteRandomDiv() create an interval or using window.requestAnimationFrame?  You could do a quick fade effect by updating the opacity in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. All you need to do is make the transition length a bit longer

```
 randomDiv.style.transition = "opacity 2s ease-out";
```

Then delay the remove by the same amount:

```
function deleteRandomDiv() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  divs[Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length)].style.opacity = "0";
  setTimeout(function() {divs[Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length)].remove()},2000);
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ovbbu1dd/)

Comment: You're fading a random div, and removing another random one after 2s. Otherwise, this solution seems viable. Thanks.

Comment: It would need some refactoring of your code to fade the same div - a global variable maybe. i'm sure you have this from here though!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function deleteRandomDiv() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  var divToRemove = divs[Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length)];
  divToRemove.style.opacity = 1;
  fadeOut(divToRemove);
}

function fadeOut(el) {
    el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity - .1;
    if(el.style.opacity > 0){
    setTimeout(function(){fadeOut(el)}, 10);
  }
  else{
    el.remove();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your `deleteRandomDiv` function, added a `getRandomInt` function:

```
console.clear();
document.body.style.position = "fixed";
document.body.style.height = "100%";
document.body.style.width = "100%";
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#EFEFEF";

var numDivs = 20;
var maxSize = 400;

function createRandomDiv() {
    var randomDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var size = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxSize) + "px";
    randomDiv.style.height = size;
    randomDiv.style.width = size;
    randomDiv.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    randomDiv.style.position = "absolute";
    randomDiv.style.top = getRandomPosition();
    randomDiv.style.left = getRandomPosition();
    randomDiv.style.display = "block";
    randomDiv.style.borderRadius = "500px";
    randomDiv.style.opacity = "1";
    randomDiv.style.transition = "opacity 0.3s ease-out";
    randomDiv.innerHTML = "&nbsp";
    randomDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/filthy-frank/images/8/8d/516c32f08e03d.png/revision/latest?cb=20151019010624)";
    randomDiv.style.backgroundSize="contain";
    document.body.appendChild(randomDiv);
}

function createDivs() {
  for(var i = 0; i < numDivs; i++) {
    createRandomDiv();
  }
}

function getRandomPosition() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "%";
}

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function deleteRandomDiv() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var div = divs[getRandomInt(0, divs.length-1)];
  div.style.opacity = "0";
  div.addEventListener('animationend', function () {
    this.remove();
  });
}

createDivs();

setInterval(function () {
  createRandomDiv();
  deleteRandomDiv();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This works, weird thing is that if you set numDivs to 1, it seems to be creating more elements than it is deleting.

Comment: Actually, this happens all the time, it's just more apparent if you set `numDivs` to a low number. I have no idea exactly what's going on, but the problem is definitely related to the `animationend` event listener. If you try to remove it – keeping only the `remove()` call – everything works as expected.